# Select and paste a code as a snippet

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Say I have a section of code e.g:

```
[StringLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Length must be less than or equal to 15")]
public string UserDefinedName0 { get; set; }

[StringLength(63, ErrorMessage = "Length must be less than or equal to 63")]
public string UserDefinedValue0 { get; set; }
```

Is there any plugin or visual studio feature or third party windows tool that allows me to copy and paste it such that I get a parameter for say "0" when I paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:
[Visual Studio Tip: Setting Up Code Snippets with Variable Parameters](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/11/16/vscodesnippets.aspx)

Comment: Right direction. Except that I do not want to create a .snippet file. Just want to copy to clipboard, put in a couple of ??? placeholders and when I paste I want to be able to tab through the regions with ??? placeholders and type in new values. Guess there isn't. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a plug-in that would do that, but can think of two solutions that might be helpful:

1. Write a short macro yourself. It's easier than you might think.
2. Use RegEx replace. Not sure if this will suite your purpose fully, but I have used it so many times to do some clever code duplication.